# Why can't python access a .mp3 file?

Tags: python, winsound

I have been building a game and I have been trying to add some background music for the menu. When I run the code though, all I get is a windows sound (Either notification or error sound, I don't know which) and then it just runs the rest of the program.

```
def background_menu():
 winsound.PlaySound("Menu Music.mp3", winsound.SND_ALIAS)

thread = Thread(target=background_menu)
thread.start()
menu_title()
```

`background_menu()` plays  the music: Which is called `'Menu Music.mp3'`.
As you can see I have used a thread to run it in the background with `from threading import Thread`
at the begginning of the code.
Then the function `menu_title()` displays the rest of the menu.
I am trying to use the thread to run it in the background. I think python just can't access the file (Which is in the same folder btw) I have also tried running as administrator and I am logged in as administrator. No syntax error appears.

Comment: I think that winsound only supports WAV files when that function is called with the SND_FILENAME flag.

Comment: @PacketLoss Thanks but I don't appear to have pygame which I need for that. Any ideas?

Comment: Install a module that can handle `mp3` . I'm unsure if Python natively supports MP3 playing.

Comment: Many of python libraries like `sounddevice` don't play mp3 or m4a natively. They requires `pydub` to convert mp3 to wav which is time consuming and inconvenient. Not sure if it is because of license - it's always better to convert those into wav or flac sort of license-free codecs.

Comment: If you don't have `pygame`, install it. At an Administrator command prompt: `pip install pygame`. The module recommends Python 3.7.7 or later.